# Python function with nested lists

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding how functions work with nested lists. For example:

```
def function(x):
   return (i for i in x)

x = function([[99, 0], [0, 99]])
print(list(x))
```

Gives the result:

```
[[99, 0], [0, 99]]
```

However, this code:

```
def function(x):
   for i in x:
       return i

x = function([[99, 0], [0, 99]])
print(list(x))
```

Gives:

```
[99, 0]
```

Why doesn't the second code print the second component of the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second code, the return function is inside the loop. Once your function sees `return` once, it's over. 
In the first code, return is called on the [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) inside the parentheses, so everything inside the parentheses is executed when you call the function.

Comment: well, it returns an iterator, a generator. The actual code inside that expression is executed lazily.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet, iteration is happening on the list of lists([[99, 0], [0, 99]]) so when the iteration takes place it will pull the first element of the list that is [99,0] and in next line its encounter return statement that causes the function to stop executing and hand a value back to whatever called it.